# require_once in class breaks Unit Test

Tags: phpunit, typo3, phpstorm

I use this at the top of my class, that I run a test against:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

require_once ExtensionManagementUtility::siteRelPath('my_ext') . 'Lib/ServiceLoader.php';

class Tx_MyOtherExt_Domain_Service_SearchService implements SingletonInterface
```

Then in my test I get an instance of that class, like this:

```
/** @var \Tx_MyOtherExt_Domain_Service_SearchService $service */
$service = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\Tx_MyOtherExt_Domain_Service_SearchService');
```

However, the test throws an error:

```
Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required 'typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Lib/ServiceLoader.php' (include_path='C:/xampp/htdocs/my_proj/site/typo3/contrib/pear/;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

How can I add the site root to the include path? The PHPSTORM settings (Settings->PHP) don't seem to make a difference.

NOTE: adding the site root to the include_path setting in php.ini works, of course. But as this path changes per project, setting this via PHPSTORM would be best.

Comment: Does `ExtensionManagementUtility::siteRelPath('my_ext')` return a valid path? Do the tests work when you run PHPUnit outside of PhpStorm?

Comment: Don't rely on [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). Use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to create absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the constant `PATH_site` to get an absolute path?
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/Constants/Index.html

Comment: I'd rather not touch the code. Although this is my own (legacy) extension I've seen it been done like this in many other extensions. So ultimately this should be solved by configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should improve writing your code. First of all, it is also about changing the running code.

**Use injection**

If you need a separate class in your code, use e.g. constructor injection to inject the object into a property. By calling `$this->getAccessibleMock` with the 5th argument to `false` the original constructor won't call and you can fake the object by using `->_set('name', $obj)``

**GeneralUtility::makeInstance**

Don't use that in the tests but `new()`. If the tests breaks, your code is wrong and should be changed instead of building the test's code around it!